# What does object.super() do? How to creating a State?

Tags: java, state

So I have this code:

```
public class A {
    private State _state;

    public abstract class State {
        protected void setState(State newState) {
            _state = newState;
        }
    }

    public A() {
        _state = new AbstractState(this);
    }
}

public abstract class AbstractState extends A.State {
    AbstractState(A a) {
        a.super();
    }
}
```

And I'm having a hard time understanding how it works.

So when a `A object` is created it creates a `AbstractState` object with that same `A object` as a parameter. And the `AbstractState` constructor, which receives that `A object`, calls `a.super()`.

From my understanding, `a.super()` calls the construtor of the super class of `A a`, which is `Object`, right? So what's the point?

I know that `AbstractState` is an abstract class. A subclass could be:

```
public class StateOne extends AbstractState {
    StateOne(A a) {
        super(a);
    }
}
```

The question remains though.

Comment: object.super() wasn't explained there. Does it do the same as super() but for object? Or is it the super from the class that Object is in?

Comment: It calls the constructor of the superclass of of `StateOne`.

Comment: I meant what does it do in AbstractState. So in `a.super()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> From my understanding, `a.super()` calls the constructor of the super class of A a, which is Object, right? So what's the point?

I think you are asking why you have to write `a.super()` rather than `super()`.

First of all, it is not calling the constructor of `A` or of the superclass of `A`.  The `super(...)` call in a constructor **always** means a constructor in the immediate superclass of the class that you are instantiating.  In this case the superclass is the inner class `A.State`.

What `a.super()` actually says is "call my super class constructor *with `a` as my enclosing instance*".

The unusual syntax is needed because the superclass is an inner class, and when an inner class is instantiated, it needs to know what **instance** of the enclosing class that it is inside.

In your example, `State` is declared as an inner class (i.e. not `static`) so the `setState` method can see the private `_state` variable of some instance the enclosing class (`A`).  The `a.super()` is necessary so that the JVM can know *which instance of `A`* is the enclosing one.

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

To call an inner class (State), it must tell it who is its super class A first. JVM can find who is the father class of StateOne, just using this statement " extends A.State" .

a.super() is corresponding to A.State

a --> A in " extends A.State ", tell inner class who is your father class (the instance of father class)
super() ----> State in "extends A.State ", it is the constructor of inner class

You can understand it like this, a common class extends use "super()/super(xx)", but extending inner class must have to know an instance of its super class first. So how to know its super class, in the constructor, use the parameter. Then, using super() calls father's constructor, like this, inner class use (my father class).super()